# Circular reference in Django model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-south, django-migrations

I would like to create two models: 1) Conversation, which stores reference to the root message with a title and 2) Message, which stores content/text of the message and a reference back to the campaign. The plan is to link messages and eventually create a conversation tree. The root message in the conversation will act as the head (entry) node of the linked network of messages.

Below is what I defined in the model files (`conversations/models.py` and `messages/models.py` respectively):

```
from messages.models import Message
class Conversation(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Conversation Title', max_length=500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    composer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    root_message =  models.ForeignKey(Message, null=True, blank=True)

from conversations.models import Conversation
class Message(models.Model):
(foreignkey very likely)
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(db_index=True, max_length=500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The problem is when I run south's `schemamigration messages --auto` or `schemamigration conversations --auto`, I run into error like this:

```
    class Campaign(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Documents\GitHub\t4s\conversations\models.py", line 11, in Conversation
    from messages.models import Message
ImportError: cannot import name Message
```

I believe this is because `Message` and `Conversation` are importing each other. But I'd like each `Message` instance to have an association with `Conversation` so that I can refer to the title of the conversation. Is there something that I can do to successfully create a `Foreignkey` field in `Message` and `Conversation` without having to change the structures of the models? Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django circular model reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466726/django-circular-model-reference)

Comment: (also see documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey , esp the second example)

Comment: Change the name of your class

Comment: @NightShadeQueen, thank you for the suggestion! I read the doc carefully around the area you pointed to and found it to be helpful. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the string value for referencing the models. However, it seems to me like both of these models should be contained within the same app. Looking at just this bit of code makes it feel like a poor design as apps shouldn't have a circular reference like this.

Also the root_message should be a OneToOneField since a message is tied to a single conversation making it impossible for a message to be the root of more than one conversation.

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Conversation Title', max_length=500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    composer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    root_message =  models.ForeignKey('messages.Message', null=True, blank=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    conversation = models.ForeignKey('conversations.Conversation', null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(db_index=True, max_length=500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. Using string value to reference the model solves the circular reference problem. In `Message` model definition, I declared: `campaign = models.ForeignKey('campaigns.Campaign', null=True, blank=True)`. Thanks for the answer and suggestion again.

Comment: Please consider my two other suggestions as well.

Comment: yes. Will do. I think it'll make the model configuration cleaner. Thank you. :)