# How can I resolve or fix Django cyclic model field dependencies?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I've a database design corresponding to the following pseudo-code:

```
class AModel(models.Model):
    c_model_instances = models.OneToOne(CModel, ...)  # "is a" relationship

class BModel(models.Model):
    a_model_instances = models.ManyToMany(AModel, ...)  # "contains" relationship

class CModel(models.Model):
    b_model_instances = models.ManyToMany(BModel, ...)  # "contains" relationship
```

Belief it or not... this design makes total sense from a business perspective :) However of course I get an error `NameError: name 'CModel' is not defined` when I try to migrate the database. How can I resolve or fix (via different design) the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django circular model reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466726/django-circular-model-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string literals, instead of an identifier that points to a model, as described in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can **use the name of the model**, rather than the model object itself.

For example:

```
class AModel(models.Model):
    c_model_instances = models.OneToOne('django_app_name.CModel', …)  # "is a" relationship

class BModel(models.Model):
    a_model_instances = models.ManyToMany(AModel, …)  # "contains" relationship

class CModel(models.Model):
    b_model_instances = models.ManyToMany(BModel, …)  # "contains" relationship
```

Django will automatically replace the string literals with references to the models.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sounds promissing. I'll try out and accept your answer soon.

Comment: I get `site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 140, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.` now.

Comment: Using `ForeignKey` with `unique=True` instead of `OneToOne` raises the same error.

Comment: Seems to work with `OneToOne`. But ` String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.`

Comment: @thinwybk: if these are in *different* apps, yes. If these are in the same app, then you can drop the prefix.

Comment: One thing to consider is that pylint-django crashes when using the `app_nam.model` syntax. This can be avoided when using just one app with the `model` syntax but not in case of several django apps.