# cannot import name in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

**Structure of app**

[image]

**areas models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from products.models import ProductModel

class ProductionLine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique=True)
```

**products models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from areas.models import ProductionLine

class ProductModel(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique=True)
    productionLine = models.ForeignKey(ProductionLine,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm trying to import ProductionLine, but when i import ProductionLine i have an error :

- File "/app/areas/models.py", line 2, in *
- from products.models import ProductModel*
- ImportError: cannot import name 'ProductModel'*

And when i delete the import of ProductionLine in products.models, everything works. I don't understand

Comment: Have you added the products app to settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379042/django-circular-model-import-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you import `ProductionLine` in products models.py and also import `ProductModel` in areas.py, which causes [circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466726/django-circular-model-reference), in this case, you can use model string instead:

```
from django.db import models
# comment this line
# from areas.models import ProductionLine

class ProductModel(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique=True)
    productionLine = models.ForeignKey('areas.ProductionLine',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [Django - Circular model import issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379042/django-circular-model-import-issue)

In ProductModel, for productionLine, do this:

```
productionLine = models.ForeignKey('areas.ProductionLine', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Also ensure that you have both the apps listed in settings.py under INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score -1):

I guess you didn't insert your apps into `installed_apps` in your `settings.py`:

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Custom Apps
    'products',
    'areas',
]

Your import statements look just fine.
```